# Validate a number value without custom validator in JSF

Tags: validation, jsf, jsf-2

I have a JSF form. I want a message to be displayed, when a user entered `0` in `qty` field and clicked on the `Add To Card` button.

Here is the JSF form:

```
<h:form>
      <h:inputText id="qtyField" value="#{booksBean.qty}">
          <!--What kind of validation should i use here?-->
          <f:ajax event="blur" render="qtyMsg"/>
       </h:inputText>

       <h:message id="qtyMsg" for="qtyField"/>

       <h:commandButton value="Add To Card"
                        action="#{booksBean.orderBook()}"
                        rendered="#{booksBean.qty>0}">
           <f:ajax execute="@form" rendered="@form"/>
       </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

Do I need a custom validator class just to simply compare a number value with a zero?

Like this:

```
@FacesValidator("myValidator")
public class MyValidator implements Validator {

@Override
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {

   if (intValue== 0 || intValue <0) {
      throw new ValidatorException(new FacesMessage(...));
   }
    //...
}
```

Is there any shorter way without creating a custom validator class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`f:validateLongRange`](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-validatelongrange-example/) for this.

```
<h:inputText value="#{backingBean.input1}">
    <f:validateLongRange minimum="1" />
</h:inputText>
```

> Checks whether the local value of a component is within a certain
>   range. The value must be any numeric type or String that can be
>   converted to a long.